# Alert display all values and also set DateTime Max

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

How to set maxTime on my code, i want to display value until 17:00 a clock, and also display all the times in an alert, right now it display only one time and the time.

```
function() {

            var toTime = new Date(result2);
            var convertUtctoTime = new Date(toTime.getTime() + toTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
            var end = new Date(convertUtctoTime);
            while (end>=fromTime) {
                var newDate = end.setTime(end.getTime()+ 30 * 60 * 1000);
                end = new Date(newDate);
                alert("Free time at" + " " + end);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the date, try checking the time in milliseconds:

```
while (end.getTime() >= fromTime.getTime()) { ...
```